# Show only two digit ofter Decimal

Tags: javascript, jsp

```
else{
  stockTable.find("tr:eq("+ index + ")")
            .find("input:eq(9)")
            .parseFloat((stockvalue[9])
            .tofixed(2)); 
}
```

Please help its not working

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

There is a toFixed method to solve this:

```
let num1 = parseFloat("7.423845204958")

console.log(num1.toFixed(2))
```

Comment: The OP already uses `toFixed(2)` in the question.

Comment: i did not understand

Comment: Your answer doesn't provide anything new or helpful. You mentioned the `toFixed` method, but you can find the method in the code in the question.